# How can I check if the current date/time is past a set date/time in variable time zones?

Tags: php, date, datetime

I'm trying to write a PHP script that will check if the current date/time is past a certain date, say 5/5/2017 at 7pm within variable timezones that the user picks.

So basically if a user selects 5/5/2017 7:00 pm in mountain time, it checks whether it is currently past that date in mountain time and returns TRUE (or false). Same thing if the user chooses central time, pacific time, etc.

I know how to do it with a regular date, but how would I approach it with the user being able to choose different timezones as well?

Comment: Give it a go, show us your best attempt and we'll help you from there :)

Comment: We are not your work monkeys, but to get an *usually* accurate timezone use GEO IP to get the timezone and convert a datetime with your date including the timezone to a unix timestamp then check with php using `time()` to compare that number, where `time()` is the current server time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using DateTime, you can specify a time and time zone then compare to the current time:

```
$date = new DateTime('2017-05-05 07:00:00', new DateTimeZone('TimezoneID'));
return ($date->getTimestamp() < time());
```

Comment: Please do not use DateTime and time()

Comment: Opinionated of course but should just use another DateTime object imo, mixing the two feels icky

Comment: Very opinionated, seems like a waste to call `new DateTime()->getTimestamp()` when `time()` does the same thing.  Not to mention time() is probably faster and uses less resources than instantiating a DateTime object.

Comment: Can I use a timezone in this format? (America/Los_Angeles) GMT-07:00? If not, what do I need to convert it to?

Comment: @kevinkt I'll point you to the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php